# Loading datepicker in ajax call, then onclick does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I am loading my datepicker script in an ajax call, which works fine and loads the datepicker as it should. The problem I am having is when i then click a day it does not fire the onclick function.

If i load the datepicker page up on its own in a seperate window then it works fine

AJAX CALL

```
function dates(str2){

  var event = findSelection("event");
  if (str2 == "")
  {
    document.getElementById("dates").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById("dates").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    }
  }


  xmlhttp.open("GET", "dates.php?event=" + 
    event + "&type=" + document.getElementById("type").value, true);

  xmlhttp.send();

}
```

dates.php

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Display inline</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
  <script>
  $(function () {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
              alert("I am an alert box!");
          }
      });
  });      </script>
</head>
<body>

Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you loading an entire html document into a div? ` document.getElementById("dates").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

dates.php (remove everything but this)

```
Date: <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Then your js code (change redystate change function to):

```
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
    {
      document.getElementById("dates").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
          numberOfMonths: 1,
          onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
              alert("I am an alert box!");
          }
      });
    }
  }
```

Or since youre using jQuery anyway change the dates function to

```
function dates(str2){
  var event = findSelection("event");
  $("#dates").load("dates.php?event=" + 
    escape(event) + "&type=" + escape($("#type").val()));
  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
     numberOfMonths: 1,
     onSelect: function (selected, evnt) {
        alert("I am an alert box!");
     }
 });
}
```